# Adding Spring Framework Support in IntelliJ - no such option

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

So, I've got a simple Maven Project and I want to add Spring Framework Support, mainly to generate Spring Config file. However, in the IntelliJ menu called Add Framework Support, I see no Spring option[image: Add Frameworks Support Menu]
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.javastart</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-di-xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-framework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I've tried reimporting Maven with no results.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**NOTE: IT'S THE ULTIMATE EDITION 2019.2.3** 
EDIT:
Spring plugins are active.[image: Spring Plugins List]

Facests:
[image]

Comment: Please see my answer below and accept answer as a solution if you've satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring framework support is available only in Ultimate Edition of IDEA.

> This feature is only supported in the Ultimate edition.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html

Edit:
Go to Plugins and on the left you see  Bundled header. Check if Spring tools are deactivated there.

Comment: They are active, the list is in Question Edit

Comment: File>Project Structure> Facets
What do you see here?

Comment: I added screenshot to Question. I see Spring with no contexts defined

Comment: Try to remove that facet and click + button and select Spring and configure it. 

If it does not work remove last facet again and try to add framework support check if there is spring.

Comment: Removing(by clicking "-", not Deleting) facet and the adding framework support worked fine. Thank You.